# javascript value for slug inside blade

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.4, slug, laravel-blade

I don't know if you could really understand what output i wanted to show. I know that there's easier way in doing this i hope someone can help .But i have this problem in creating route using slugs inside a blade.

this is for creating a map:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i];
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title
            });

            //Attach click event to the marker.
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    //Wrap the content inside an HTML DIV in order to set height and width of InfoWindow.
                    infoWindow.setContent("<div style = 'width:200px;min-height:40px'>"
                        + "<h3>" +  data.title + "</h3> "
                        + data.description
                        + "<a href='{{ url("/". data.title . ->slug) }}'>View"
                        + "</a></div>");
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        }
```

and this part right here is my problem:

```
+ "<a href='{{ url("/". data.title . ->slug) }}'>View"
                            + "</a></div>");
```

I want the value of `data.title` to be converted to php so i can use it as a slug.

Hmmm, anyways `data.lat, data.lng,data.description and data.title` where fetch from here, and was json_encoded

```
foreach($query as $item) {
        $data[] = [
            'title' => $item->school_name,
            'lat' => $item->latitude,
            'lng' => $item->longitude,
            'description' => $item->enrollment_sy_2014_2015,
            'id' => $item->school_id

        ];
    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Either You can add additional 'slug' => $item->slug (if you have this member), Then call +'<a href="{{ url('/') }}"'+data.slug+'>View</a>'  OR +'<a href="{{ url('/') }}" '+data.title+' >View</a>'

Comment: Whoa! I hadn't thought about that... I'll try that thanks.. Uhm, btw @Shan, i cant +1 your comment :/

Comment: Hmm.. It returns null

Comment: For which variable ?

Comment: I did try to echo `data.slug` since i am getting no results, then it returns nullNaN.. I think the problem now, is my controller or the routes.